# Random number from an interval with bounds near maximum and minimum integer value

Tags: java, arrays, random

I have read other posts on this topic but I have not found an answer so far.

Given an array of length of 1000, find its lowest and highest values. These values are the bounds within which a random number is generated.

Finding lowest and highest numbers of an array is OK for me, but generating the number within those bounds is not.

Seems like a simple `int number = random.nextInt(max - min) + min;` would do the trick, but it does not, because:

a) max can be 100 and min can be -100000, which becomes a negative bound and causes error
b) other solutions like `random.nextInt(Math.abs(min) + Math.abs(max)) - Math.abs(min)` simply fail, because within an integer data type, adding two positive numbers together can result in a negative value if the maximum value is exceeded.

So let's say I want to generate a random number within -2147483648 and 2147483647. How do I do that?

Thanks alot...

Comment: this sounds eerily like a homework assignment..

Comment: @JasonV It is :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `max==100` and `min==-100000`, then `max-min == +100100` (notice no `abs()`) and

```
int number = random.nextInt(max - min) + min;
```

will produce the value you are looking for.  Don't overcomplicate things.

You WILL run into problems if `max-min` (i.e. the range) is greater than 2<sup>31</sup>-1, but to get around that just use `long` instead.  This is a little more complex since there's no method `Random#nextLong(long bound)`, so you have to just use `nextLong()` and scale the result to your range.

There are several approaches to scaling a `long` to a smaller range, such as

```
randomLong % range
```

If you really want to scale it to -2147483648..2147483647 then just extract 32 bits from anywhere in the `long` and turn that into an `int`.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. How do I scale a random long result into a custom range? EDIT: I accualy found an article about that. Thanks Jim.

Comment: Updated answer.